# AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, datetime, time

For test, I wrote a program that prints out time difference and it worked out perfectly. Here is the code in test.py

```
import time

start = time.time()

while True:
    if time.time() - start >= 59:
        print(time.time() - start)
        start = time.time()
```

As I said, it works here; but when I copy the same code into my main code in main.py, it throws this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 81, in <module>
  if time.time() - start >= 59:
AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'time'
```

Why does it work on my terminal and test.py but throws an error in main.py and I'm not even importing datetime?

I have searched online for causes yet nothing and I need to use the code in my main.py. This is my main.py:

```
import win32com.client #pip install pywin32 if not installed
import math
import time
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pygame as pg
from pywintypes import com_error

x = math.inf
counter = 0
start=time.time()

 while True:
       print(start)
        if time.time() - start >= 59:
            counter = 0
            start = time.time()
        counter +=1
        print(counter)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `time` from `datetime` instead of from `datetime.time`?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not clear; I'm importing time as I did in test.py not 'from datetime import time'.

Comment: Can you post your entire `main.py` source file? The error says it's happening on line `81` which the file shown is far too short for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  `import time as t`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import math
    import time as t
    x = math.inf
    counter = 0
    start=t.time()

    while True:
       print(start)
       if t.time() - start >= 59:
            counter = 0
            start = t.time()
       counter +=1
       print(counter)
```

OUTPUT:

```
652238.8331313
56259
1550652238.8331313
56260
1550652238.8331313
56261
1550652238.8331313
.
.
.
```